# Erro na chamada de página JSF + Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho o seguinte menu:

```xml
    <h:form>
    <p:menubar style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 20px">
        <p:submenu label="Cadastros">
            <p:menuitem value="Pessoa" />
            <p:menuitem value="Lançamento"
                action="/CadastroLancamentos?faces-redirect=true" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Consultas">
            <p:menuitem value="Pessoas" />
            <p:menuitem value="Lançamentos"
                action="/ConsultaLancamentos?faces-redirect=true" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Sistema">
            <p:menuitem value="Sair" action="#{loginBean.logout}" />
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

Quando estou na página `/ConsultaLancamentos` e seleciono a opção de cadastro de lançamentos, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
    jan 26, 2017 10:07:19 AM org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler logException
SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/errorpages/error.xhtml' will be shown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.destroyBeans(ViewScopeContextManager.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.clear(ViewScopeContextManager.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processPreDestroyViewMap(ViewScopeManager.java:335)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processEvent(ViewScopeManager.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeEventListener.processEvent(ViewScopeEventListener.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap.clear(UIViewRoot.java:1850)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.clearViewMapIfNecessary(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

jan 26, 2017 10:07:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/dockerapp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.destroyBeans(ViewScopeContextManager.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.clear(ViewScopeContextManager.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processPreDestroyViewMap(ViewScopeManager.java:335)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.processEvent(ViewScopeManager.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeEventListener.processEvent(ViewScopeEventListener.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap.clear(UIViewRoot.java:1850)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.setViewRoot(FacesContextImpl.java:478)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.renderErrorPageView(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:319)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:240)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Estou usando o OmniFaces para redirecionar o erro. Ele diz quer vai exibir a página de erro mas não exibe nesse caso e se eu entrar no link pelo navegador o erro não ocorre, ou seja, está sendo exibido apenas quando é selecionado no menu.

Comment: Poste o código da página ConsultaLancamentos.

Comment: Essa barra antes do nome da página deve existir mesmo? Teste sem, por favor

Comment: Aparentemente o problema ocorre no tratamento de excessões com a configuração do **FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory**. Após comentar o código: `<exception-handler-factory>
   org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
  </exception-handler-factory>` a navegação voltou a funcionar normalmente sem nenhuma alteração. O mais estranho é que quando ocorre na página de erro o OmniFaces informa o que me leva a pensar que o problema está ocorrendo antes da chamada da página de erro.

Comment: @igorventurelli Com a remoção da barra o comportamento é igual. Com omnifaces dá problema e sem ele redireciona normal.